# PHP script doesn't work when passed non-standard A-Z 0-9 characters

Tags: php

I have a PHP script:

```
<?php
$dbh = new PDO('sqlite:database.db');
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE user = :user');
$sth->bindParam(':user', $_POST['user'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->execute();
$result = $sth->fetchAll();
if( empty( $result ) )
{
     echo "0";
}
else
{
     echo "1";
}
?>
```

It works correctly when passed standard A-Z 0-9 characters but when `$_POST['user']` is something like `Çärmêñ™` it incorrectly returns `0`. The user is present in the database so it should return `1`.

How do I get it to work correctly?

### Update

Yes as mentioned in the comments it appears that the database is the issue here:

```
sqlite> SELECT * FROM t1;
Çärmêñ™|098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6
sqlite> 

sqlite> SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE user = 'Çärmêñ™';
sqlite>
```

but the encoding is already set to UTF-8:

```
sqlite> PRAGMA encoding;
UTF-8
```

Comment: How Çärmêñ™ user is saved in database?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Comment: Check your database encodings and use UTF-8 everywhere. See @Fred-ii-'s link.

Comment: Please can you check my update?

Comment: is Çärmêñ™|098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6 supposed to be just Çärmêñ™?

Comment: @Aris no. `098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6` is the hex. The `user` column (columns separated by `|`) is `Çärmêñ™`.

Answer (score 0):

try using to scape the strings from the $_POST variable using `mysqli_real_scape_string`.

```
$user = mysqli_real_scape_string("conecction",$_POST['user']);
```

then try with select : 
`$sth = mysqli_query('SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE user = '$user');`